# Why is mlockall occasionally slow?

Tags: linux, real-time, ada, rhel, timing

Background: we've recently updated our Operating System from RHEL 6.7 MRG to RHEL 7.7 (with RealTime).  Our RealTime Ada Radar Applications run mlockall (c binding) to lock into memory at startup (yes, I understand this is rarely necessary, and likely isn't for all of the applications, but is required for many).

The Problem:
Since the upgrade, mlockall occasionally takes over 2 minutes, where it usually takes < 1 second.  What could be causing this behavior?

I was pointed at file cache/memory buffer, so we ran some tests after dropping caches, but it didn't seem to have a positive effect.

Comment: Have à look at the process size, depending on the flags, the shared libraries that are loaded, locking all the address space can be consumming. It may not be a good idea to do that...